# What difficulty will I face if I use same elasticsearch instance for dev and prod

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am planning to use same elasticsearch instance for dev/qa and prod env.
Using snapshot and aliasing I can achieve this.

But I am not aware about the side effects of doing this.

Simultaneously I have budget constrain and my elasticsearch is deplyed on AWS.

Also, can anyone suggest any better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a few thoughts:

If you decide to run load testing on your QA index, your clients using the PROD index will suffer.

If you need to venture into configuration tuning (and you will), you'll have to restart your cluster for changes to take effect, that will also disrupt PROD.

Those are the two big NO-NO for having all your environments in the same cluster. If budget is a constraint, you can definitely have dev + QA in the same cluster, but the PROD one should be standalone for obvious reasons.